# How to tell Postgresql table column using utc without time zone?

Tags: postgresql

I want to import a table column which is a datetime using UTC without time zone.

I used to getdateutc() in MS SQL. But I couldn't find for the PostgreSQL.

I just find just without time zone part in PostgreSQL. But I couldn't find utc part.

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest(
   created_date timestamp without time zone
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a another working solution for my question.

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest(
  created_date timestamp not null default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the current timestamp as it looks in UTC, use

```
current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

`current_timestamp` returns a `timestamp with time zone` (an "absolute timestamp"), and `AT TIME ZONE` will convert it to a `timestamp without time zone` that shows what an UTC wall clock would display at that moment.